# How to pass multiple values to a jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass multiple values to a jquery dialogbox and show those values in the table in the dialog box ...

I am rending the html content in the dialogbox through the ajax call

this is my ajax call

```
$.get(url, function (data, status) {
    $("#dlgMessages").html(data);
    $("#dlgMessages").dialog('open');
}).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(jqXHR.status);
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need / can't pass the variables directly to the dialog box. What you can do is use jquery to find the elements inside the dialog box (using an ID on those elements will be easiest) and change their content like this:

```
$("#cell-id").text(data[0]);
```

It will vary a little depending on how you are sending the data from your server but the idea is the same. Find the element inside the dialog where you want to display value and change its content either using `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying me about the problem .. and for giving an idea